# Logging variable created with new String() returns the entire object

Tags: javascript

There must be something I have missed here, but after reading the MDN docs, it seems like there isn't any immediate method that achieves what I was trying to do.

When trying to `console.log()` a variable created with `new String("text")`, the console prints `[String: 'text']` instead of the expected result of `text`.

```
let testString = "test string!";
let testString2 = String("test string!");
let testString3 = new String("test string!");

console.log(testString);   // test string!
console.log(testString2);  // test string!
console.log(testString3);  // [String: 'test string!']
```

What method is available to print just the text value for `testString3`?

Comment: [string primitives vs string object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_primitives_and_String_objects)

Comment: try logging `typeof` for each of those variables to understand why

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the link, I guess I didn't read far enough. I actually did attempt to test their example of `console.log(eval(s2.valueOf()))` but had a meatware level error of trying that directly into the Firefox console, which always returned an `undefined` result and threw me off for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast it to a plain string first with `String`:

```js
let testString = "test string!";
let testString2 = String("test string!");
let testString3 = new String("test string!");

console.log(testString);   // test string!
console.log(testString2);  // test string!
console.log(String(testString3));  // test string!
```

The `testString3` is actually a string object, but you want just the primitive. Calling `String` without `new` results in a primitive string being returned.

Comment: or use `.valueOf()` *A String object can always be converted to its primitive counterpart with the valueOf() method.* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_primitives_and_String_objects

Comment: Thanks. Between yourself and @JaromandaX I think we've covered the error of my ways. :)